# "Application validation was skipped" because "the bundle “ITunesSoftwareService” couldn’t be loaded"

Tags: ios, frameworks, xcode4, app-store-connect, application-loader

Trying to build an iOS app, I get the warning "Application validation was skipped," and the Application Loader rejects my binary because the code signing step has failed. I never had any problems building and submitting with Xcode 3. This is my first time attempting to build and submit with Xcode 4. I don't know what the "ITunesSoftwareService" framework is and I don't explicitly use it anywhere. I'm a bit baffled - any help would be appreciated. Here is the full build log:

```
Validate "/Users/lukebradford/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Random_Acts_of_Haiku-fbxqwasqdxqcoofxwybyjbxiuwvp/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Random Acts of Haiku.app"
    cd "/Users/lukebradford/Documents/My Apps/Random Acts of Haiku"
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    setenv PRODUCT_TYPE com.apple.product-type.application
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation "/Users/lukebradford/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Random_Acts_of_Haiku-fbxqwasqdxqcoofxwybyjbxiuwvp/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Random Acts of Haiku.app"

2011-10-02 00:34:21.486 Validation[73657:607] Could not load framework at “file://localhost/Developer/Applications/Utilities/Application%20Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/” (err = Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3587 UserInfo=0x200033ec0 "The bundle “ITunesSoftwareService” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources." (dlopen_preflight(/Developer/Applications/Utilities/Application Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/ITunesSoftwareService): Library not loaded: @rpath/ITunesConnectFoundation.framework/Versions/A/ITunesConnectFoundation
  Referenced from: /Developer/Applications/Utilities/Application Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/ITunesSoftwareService
  Reason: image not found))
warning: Application validation was skipped.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the `/Developer/Applications/Utilities/Application Loader.app` App was corrupted when installing Xcode.  My suggestion is to uninstall / reinstall Xcode.  The Application Loader app is necessary to validate and submit an App to Apple for review.

You can also try installing the new iTunes Beta 7/8 if your using Xcode 4.2 dev preview, that might contain some required libraries that your missing.